# "It were students ...' or 'It was students...'?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

Consider:

> It were or was the students who wanted the teacher to declare

Is there a way to identify when a collective noun will take a singular verb and when it will take a plural verb?

Comment: Note that the original sentence with out being a *cleft sentence* is *the students wanted the teacher to declare*, this may cause the confusion on using *were* or *was*, but when it comes to a cleft, you use *was.*

Comment: In the English West Country dialect, it would be *"It were they students..."*

Comment: Note that if you put "If" in front of the sentence, the correct answer to this question changes: "**If** it **were** the students..." and "It **was** the students..." are both correct. Common usage has pretty much made "**If** it **was** the students..." also accepted by pretty much everyone, but if you want to get as precise as possible, "were" is more correct when "if" is involved.

Answer (score 9):

The singular subject "It" takes the singular verb "was." Thus,

> **"It was the students who wanted the teacher to declare."**

If the subject was "the students," then it would take a plural verb; e. g.,

> **"The students were hoping the teacher would declare it was time to play."**